# Access from outer network to BaseHTTPRequestHandler python3

Tags: python-3.x, server

I'm building a BaseHTTPRequestHandler server using python3 for saving data. I succeeded in connecting to this server from devices connected to my network. Does it possible to connect to it from outer networks? If not, how can I add that function?
I tried connecting to the computers ip address but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using port forward, but it didn't worked.